# How to plot without creating different variables in Python

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to plot the number of Covid cases per department in my country, however, I would like to know a shorter way to do so. I am creating different variables for each department but it takes so many lines of code. Is there a shorter way to do so? Please advise. Thanks.

The excel file can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/dferreira-ds/Covid-19-Colombia/blob/master/2020-07-03.xlsx

This is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('2020-07-03.xlsx')

df_cases_day_bogota = df.groupby(['Nombre_depa', 'Fecha_not'])['Caso'].count().loc['Bogotá D.C.']
df_cases_day_barranquilla = df.groupby(['Nombre_depa', 'Fecha_not'])['Caso'].count().loc['Barranquilla D.E.']
df_cases_day_atlantico = df.groupby(['Nombre_depa', 'Fecha_not'])['Caso'].count().loc['Atlántico']
df_cases_day_valle = df.groupby(['Nombre_depa', 'Fecha_not'])['Caso'].count().loc['Valle del Cauca']
df_cases_day_cartagena = df.groupby(['Nombre_depa', 'Fecha_not'])['Caso'].count().loc['Cartagena D.T. y C.']
df_cases_day_antioquia = df.groupby(['Nombre_depa', 'Fecha_not'])['Caso'].count().loc['Antioquia']
df_cases_day_santander = df.groupby(['Nombre_depa', 'Fecha_not'])['Caso'].count().loc['Santander']

df_cases_day_bogota.plot(label='Bogotá D.C.')
df_cases_day_barranquilla.plot(label='Barranquilla')
df_cases_day_atlantico.plot(label='Atlantico')
df_cases_day_valle.plot(label='Valle del Cauca')
df_cases_day_cartagena.plot(label='Cartagena')
df_cases_day_antioquia.plot(label='Antioquia')
df_cases_day_santander.plot(label='Santander')

plt.title('Evolution number of cases Bogotá D.C.')
plt.xlabel('Date diagnosis')
plt.ylabel('Number of Cases')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
departments = ["Bogotá D.C.", "Barranquilla", "Atlantico", "..."]
for department in departments:
    df_cases_day = df.groupby(['Nombre_depa', 'Fecha_not'])['Caso'].count().loc[department]
    df_cases_day.plot(label=department)
```

If your code works then just adding a list and a for-loop like that should help. This is instead of the 2 big blocks of code.